# How can i refresh the RecyclerView and populate that with new Json when swiping down refreshLayout

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, pull-to-refresh

I have a RecyclerView in the `ArchiveActivity` , it's populate with json , every thing is ok but when i swipe down the refresh layout , nothing happens , now my question is how can i retrieve the new `json` and populate the `RecyclerView` and doesn't have conflict with `setOnScrollListenerMethod` :

This is the `activity_archive.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e6e6e6"
    tools:context=".activities.ArchiveActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/archiveToolbar"
        android:background="#34465d"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnVideo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/archiveToolbar"
        android:text="Video Activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout_archive"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/archiveRecylerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnVideo"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the `ArchiveActivity` :

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.majid.aparat.R;
import com.majid.aparat.adapter.ArchiveRecyclerAdapter;
import com.majid.aparat.app.AppController;
import com.majid.aparat.pojo.VideoData;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ArchiveActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    // ============ Global Variables ================ //
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    List<VideoData> videoDataList = new ArrayList<VideoData>();
    RecyclerView archiveRecyclerView;
    ArchiveRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    private String after_url;

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_archive);

        String TAG = ArchiveActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        setUpToolbar();

        // ==========  btn Video Activity =========== //
        Button btnVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVideo);
        btnVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ArchiveActivity.this, WatchActivity.class));
            }
        });

        //======== SwipeRefreshLayout init ======//

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout_archive);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.red , R.color.green , R.color.blue);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        sendJsonRequest();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                } , 1500 );
            }
        });

        // =========================  sending jsonRequest ======================= //
        sendJsonRequest();
        showPD();
        //========================= initialize recyclerView  ===========================//

        archiveRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.archiveRecylerView);
        archiveRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ArchiveActivity.this);
        archiveRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        archiveRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                loadMore();
                Toast.makeText(ArchiveActivity.this , "onLoadMore is calling" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        adapter = new ArchiveRecyclerAdapter(this, videoDataList);
        archiveRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    //========================= send json request ===========================//
    private void sendJsonRequest() {

        //========================= get Category intent ===========================//
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String catUrl = intent.getStringExtra("category");

        String fUrl = String.format("http://www.aparat.com//etc/api/categoryvideos/%s", catUrl);

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, fUrl, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                videoDataList.clear();
                parsJsonResponse(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("TAG", error.toString());
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }

      //========================= parse json response ===========================//

private void parsJsonResponse(JSONObject response) {

    if (response != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject ui = response.getJSONObject("ui");
            after_url =  ui.getString("pagingForward");

            JSONArray categoryViedeos = response.getJSONArray("lastvideos");
            for (int i = 0; i < categoryViedeos.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentVideo = categoryViedeos.getJSONObject(i);

                VideoData viNew = new VideoData();

                viNew.setVideoThumbnail(currentVideo.getString("small_poster"));
                viNew.setVideoTitle(currentVideo.getString("title"));
                viNew.setVideoCount(currentVideo.getString("visit_cnt"));
                viNew.setVideoDate(currentVideo.getString("sdate"));

                videoDataList.add(viNew);
            }
            adapter.addMoreItems(videoDataList);
            hidePD();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


    //========================= LoadMore for infinitie scroll  ===========================//

    private void loadMore() {
        //Toast.makeText(ArchiveActivity.this , "we are loading !!!" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        showPD();

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, after_url, (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                hidePD();
                parsJsonResponse(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Error
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }

    //========================= setUpToolbar ===========================//
    private void setUpToolbar() {

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String catName = intent.getStringExtra("catName");

        Toolbar archiveToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.archiveToolbar);
        //Toast.makeText(this , catUrl , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        setSupportActionBar(archiveToolbar);
        archiveToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(catName);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_left);

    }

    //========================= showPD Method ===========================//
    private void showPD() {
        if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("در حال بارگزاری ");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }

    //========================= hidePD Method  ===========================//
    private void hidePD() {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

and This is `ArchiveRecyclerAdapter` :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.majid.aparat.adapter.ArchiveRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder;
import com.majid.aparat.pojo.VideoData;
import com.majid.aparat.R;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by majid on 18/01/2016.
 */
public class ArchiveRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArchiveRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //================== Global Var
    Context context;
    List<VideoData> videoDataList ;

    //=================== Constructor  ============================= //

    public ArchiveRecyclerAdapter(Context context , List<VideoData> videoDataList) {

        this.context = context;
        this.videoDataList = videoDataList;
    }

    //===================  ViewHolder ============================= //
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        private ImageView imgThumbnailVideo;
        private TextView txtTitleVideo;
        private TextView txtCountVideo;
        private TextView txtDateVideo;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            imgThumbnailVideo = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumnailVideo);
            txtTitleVideo = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtVideoTitle);
            txtDateVideo = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtVideoDate);
            txtCountVideo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtVideoCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext() , txtTitleVideo.getText() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    }


    //=================== OnCreateViewHolder ============================= //
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_item_row , null);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(rootView);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    //=================== onBindViewHolder ============================= //
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();

        VideoData currentVideoData = videoDataList.get(position);

        Glide.with(context).load(currentVideoData.getVideoThumbnail()).into(holder.imgThumbnailVideo);
        holder.txtTitleVideo.setText(currentVideoData.getVideoTitle());
        holder.txtCountVideo.setText(currentVideoData.getVideoCount());
        holder.txtDateVideo.setText(currentVideoData.getVideoDate());

    }

    //=================== getItemCount   ============================= //
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return videoDataList.size();
    }

 //=================== addMoreItems ========================== //

    public void addMoreItems(List<VideoData> videoDataList){
        this.videoDataList.addAll(videoDataList);
    }
   }
```

Comment: Show `ArchiveRecyclerAdapter ` class code also

Comment: In your `addMoreItems` refresh your adapter

Comment: and can i remove `adapter.notify` after that , my mean in parseJsonResponse

Comment: @kianarahimi Did you debug on loadMore()? What array list data size you'r getting? If you solve by yourself then its good. But if you can't then add me on skype. My id is `gupiyushkumarv`. Will discuss there.

Answer (score 0):

Just calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` will not add new items in current Adapter Data-Source.

To get it work create a method in `ArchiveRecyclerAdapter` for adding new items in Data-Source like:

```
public void addMoreItems(List<VideoData> videoDataList){
   this.videoDataList.addAll(videoDataList);
}
```

Now call `addMoreItems` method in `parsJsonResponse` before calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: i add the `adapter.addMoreItems(videoDataList)` before the `adapter.notify` but still happen nothing

Comment: i add `addMoreItem`  to adapter and i call that befor `notify`

Comment: @kianarahimi: Add breakpoint at `adapter.addMoreItems(videoDataList);` line and check it's calling or not